# How to display number of records in the database on the HTML page dynamically

Tags: java, html

I have a web application, in which the total number of registered users are displayed at the bottom of the page. This count is retrieved from the database table.

Now, I want the count to be changed whenever a record is inserted in the DB table (a new user registered) without loading the page. So if a user gets registered now, the count need to be increased by one.

Technologies used  : HTML , Java

Comment: JavaScript, AJAX, maybe jQuery?

Comment: You could take a look at nodeJS

Comment: Server-Sent Events ??

Answer (score 0):

You could use a web service with jquery/ajax to retrieve that data that way you don't need to refresh page to get new count.  You could setup a timer and hit the web service every 30 seconds or so to see if the count has changed.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do the ajax call on every particular time interval for getting this count updated because Backend(Server) cannot put  a request to webpage(client ) to update this.